# Query Help. CASE within a WHERE IN SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

I have a query that uses a WHERE IN SELECT statement to check user levels within a table and return entries based on the level from another table.

```
SELECT * from table2
where user_level IN (select
         table1.user_level
         from table1
         where user_id=1);
```

My user levels are L1, L2 and L3.

How can I adjust the query so if the users level is L1, only L1 will be returned, and if the users level is L2 then both L1 and L2 will be returned, and if the users level is L3 then L1, L2 and L3 will be returned?

MySQL 8.*

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Which table is holding the users level `L1`?  Why did you change table names to `table1` and `table2`, and not to meaning full names ?

Comment: @Luuk , table1 is holding the levels. table2 is holding the data. It wasn’t obfuscated on purpose, I just had the snippet available.

Comment: @D-Shih , sure. I’m on mobile now, but when back to my mac later I’ll put an example together.

Comment: I think I just thought of an easier way. I’ll change my user_levels to just numbers and use >= to compare. So, where the sub select query is >= user_level. That should be simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Selecting based on some variable (i.e. `@level`) can be done like this:

```
SET @level = 'L2';

select * from users where (@level='L1' and user_level = 'L1' )
                        or (@level='L2' and user_level in ('L1','L2'))
                        or (@level='L3' and user_level in ('L1','L2','L3'))
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d41c24d2b0e1f7404a9f82dca192ff3c)

NOTE: I do know this is not a direct answer to your question, and that you need to apply this to your situation.

Comment: I thought about variables, but if I decided to put the query into a view, then it wouldn’t be an option.

Comment: I just used a variable , because of unknow table design on your side...